# cordova-plugin-file-transfer not uploading file to server

Tags: php, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on cordova project that uploads photos to server. While testing this for android, success callback is called but file not uploaded to server.
Destination folder in server is present with necessary permission.

Following is the Javascript section

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey  = "myphoto";
options.fileName = filetoupload.substr(filetoupload.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(filetoupload, encodeURI(websrvs_base_url), win, fail, options);
```

In server PHP code is

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

if($_FILES['myphoto']['size'] > 0) {
    $path = $ROOT_PATH . "mypics/";
    $tmpname1 = $_FILES['myphoto']['tmp_name'];
    $ptname1 = $_FILES['myphoto']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmpname1, $path . $ptname11);

    echo 'success';
}
```

On checking `$_FILES['myphoto']['error']` returns 7

Server has following setting regarding file upload

`file_uploads - On`

`memory_limit - 128M`

`post_max_size - 64M`

`upload_max_filesize - 100M`

Should I added any additional headers in PHP script to receive the file from app?

Comment: First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On

Comment: @Naitik PHP yes it has necessary setting, see my edit

Comment: Pelease try with this example https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/file/filetransfer/filetransfer.html

Comment: example is similar to what I have in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a server issue, our demo server was disk full and it didn't allow uploading photos from app.

We will have to check the space available for /tmp folder in server as this will be used as a temporary storage before uploading the file to actual destination. Files will not upload if /tmp folder is full or if there is any limitation.